# Send button press over RF

Tags: electronics, rf

I'm trying to send a button press over RF (performing a closed circuit operation on the receiving end).

I have a controller with an UP and DOWN button. Unfortunately I am limited to the cable length, and would like to extend it with radio frequency. The controller has one cable for GND and one each for the corresponding UP and DOWN buttons.

The RF units is the typical 433mhz bought online (ebay).

Can I in someway send the signal over RF (directly on the data pin of the transmitter) without hooking it up to a microcontroller (Arduino)?

Comment: You could buy specialized an encoder/decoder IC pair like the HT12D and HT12E. They will serve as a bridge between your controller and the RF module; no need for an MCU. I've used them to control an RC car, so they should work just fine for sending 2 button presses.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need a micro-controller at both the sending, and receiving sides.

eBay does set RF remotes with a few buttons. This might be easier and cheaper than making your own.

Comment: Here what might suit you http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/DC-5V-433mHz-2-Channel-Wireless-Delay-Relay-Remote-Controller-/281937100910

Comment: The reason you need a micro-controller at each end is the radio doesn't send data in a digital way.  It modulates the signal it sends to encode the data.  I'm afraid that's about as far a I got before I got lost and decided to give up.